# What do the Dota 2 ranks mean in the context of individual unranked games?

Tags: dota-2

When I look at my matches on https://www.dotabuff.com, I see that it includes ranks like Archon, Crusader, Guardian etc. with each game.

However, all these games are unranked (and I have never played a ranked game before) so what is the significance of it?

Sources would be an appreciated addition to answers.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps its there just for the fun of it? Don't see any other reason why.  It's probably just a way of showing how you performed for that match, casual or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the average ranks of the lobby you played in.
There might be other players in your lobby who were ranked and based on your gameplay they are assigned a virtual rank.
Unranked uses a hidden MMR for unranked players to map them against similar players (I think).

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learndota2/comments/y6g69t/dotabuff_rank_info_in_unranked_matches/) is a related Reddit question.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim